# Receiver is getting really hot

Tags: quadcopter, flight-controller

I am building a quadcopter and I am on the last part of it (normally the exciting part) where I bind the controller to the receiver.

I can get the receiver, which is plugged into the quadcopter, to be recognized by the controller. The problem is that I can't get the controller to rotate the propellers.

**When I touch the receiver it is hot.** Not just warm, but very hot. I replaced the receiver already since it looked like the heat was too much and melted something on it.

**Any thoughts as to why the receiver is so hot?** Maybe it's because I hooked something up incorrectly? Perhaps the heat is causing the controller not to turn the motors?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

**HARDWARE:**

- Controller - FlySky FS-i6
- Receiver - FS-iA6 (6 channels, 2.4 GHZ)
- Power Supply - Tattu R-Line 14.8V 1300mAh

The board it connects to is using 5v.

Comment: How much voltage is hooked up to the receiver?

Comment: `unknown receiver` + `unknown controller` + `unknown power supply` = `no solution`

Comment: I updated the post with my hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues that I resolved...

Firstly, I re-soldered the wires to the NAZE. I wanted to make sure that the connections were correct and it seemed they might be off.

Secondly, I switched the receiver to the iA6B.

The receiver is not heating up anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Either the voltage supply to the receiver is too high, or something's not right about what you're trying to drive it with.

Compare the voltage supply to the receiver to the rated voltage of the receiver.  If the receiver specifies a voltage range (i.e. 3V - 5.5V), then the supply needs to be within that range.  If the receiver doesn't specify  a range, then +/- 10% is probably an OK range to assume.

If that's OK, try disconnecting everything from the receiver except for power, and see if it gets hot.  If you have a spare servo lying around (and if the receiver will take a servo), plug it in and see if it works.

Comment: Okay, I finally got around to checking the voltage. On the board it is soldered to is 5v and the receiver is 4.0-6.5v/DC